# GPU VS Parallel processing CPU

Tags: c++, assembly, gpu, cpu

As you have written in the title, which one is faster processing speed for machine learning and image processing than GPU and parallel CPU processing?
Also, programs of the GPU are written in C / C ++, and the program on the CPU which performs parallel processing shall be written in assembly language and C / C ++ Or if it's all in assembly language.

Even if the processing speed of the CPU is slower, can we perform real-time processing smoothly for object detection of image processing?

Comment: You can usually gain lot of performance first by sorting out your data structures layout, optimizing for target platform cache and memory limitations, etc... C++ compilers are very good at this moment, and if you have your algorithms and data structures well designed, the performance will be already OK-ish. Then you can profile+check the machine code from compiler, eventually rewriting some time critical code paths in assembly, but that's like the final step after everything else has been reasonably exhausted, because writing good assembly is expensive process, making future changes expensive.

Comment: Thank you very much for your precious opinion.
By the way, which is fast as a result?

Comment: The fastest code is the one which does not exist (also it has no bugs), so I prefer to prune-first all tasks to figure out what is essential for the task, and what can be omitted. Your whole question feels a bit wrong, you either have fixed HW and then you may ask what can be detected on it, with what accuracy and what latency, or you have certain accuracy+speed requirements, after reaching that on "unlimited" HW you measure what HW you need to have such accuracy, with some plan for particular optimizations to hit the target. Mind you, "detecting objects" is not very exact science, more guess.

Comment: btw, just recalled it now, the nVidia has special chips dedicated for automotive industry, which are WAY MORE performant (per watt) than common CPU for neural network tasks, and optimized for that. The nVidia chips are presented to have enough horsepower to operate the autonomous car recognition systems, so check for those specs to get idea what's required for partial detection in car (that doesn't need to recognize too much, mostly just movement and position and "solidity" of objects, but doesn't matter too much if it mislabels kid as bike, etc., that's just fine tuning of results).

Answer (score 1):

Most machine learning problems (e.g., most neural network code) is sufficiently parallel that it runs substantially faster on the GPU than the CPU.

Image processing...well, that's exactly what GPUs are designed for. So, it's probably not exactly a huge surprise that GPUs are better at most image processing tasks than CPUs.

Doing real-time image processing smoothly in a CPU depends. If you mean something like one low-resolution image per second, and fairly simple object detection, then yes, a decent CPU can probably keep up just fine. If you're talking about more complex object detection on 4K video at 30 or (god help you) 60 frames per second, then it's going to be a *lot* more difficult for the CPU to keep up (my first guess would be that it's just not going to happen).

Comment: By the way, although darknet famous for machine learning seems to be faster in processing speed on CPU, it seems to be 500 times faster in GPU.